# Is it possible to JOIN on the NEW/OLD tables inside a trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I want to join the incoming data (in the NEW virtual table) with other database tables inside an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. Is this possible in SQLite?

Pseudo-ish code:

```
create trigger vTableC_OnInsert
instead of insert on vTableC
begin 

insert into tableA (column1, column2)

select
    NEW.column1,
    b.column2
from
    tableB b 
        JOIN 
    NEW n
        on b.vTableC_id = n.id

end
```

I tried, but get this error: "no such table: main.new".

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is no, since according to the docs SQLite only supports FOR EACH ROW triggers, so there's actually no virtual NEW table, just an array of fields from each iteration.